# Java - two selection listeners on one SWT Button

Tags: java, multithreading, button, swt

I am currently working on a rather bigger project, so I can't test it myself without destroying the code a bit. Is it possible to have two selection listeners, which will perform different tasks? It could be done easily with just one selection listeners and an if statement, but my program uses multithreading, so this option doesn't suit me very well. Basicly the second action of the button should cancel the first action, if it's still running. Any other ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: post some code you tried with.

Comment: You can have multiple selection listeners but they will all run every time you press the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. Not just for this specific case, but in every GUI framework I know of, if you can add a listener for some event, you can add many such listeners.